# Breaking Down Large SQL Command / Performance (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlperformance, sql-server-profiler

I apologize if this question is too general, I can post and example code, but it may not be reproducible because there is no access to the actual database.

Suppose I have a big MySQL query with a lot of joins and unions, as well as functions like `concat`, `date`, various time and date conversion functions. And it uses a lot of tables, nested select queries etc. Lets suppose it is a `select` query.

My questions is, where would one start, if they need to optimize this script to run faster? Currently its taking hours to complete. Furthermore, If I run stand-alone chunks of code from it (including some nested queries, etc.) they run much faster. Therefore there are one or a few bottlenecks. Perhaps certain tables are not indexed properly.

I am aware of profiling and bench-marking as well as `explain` functionality in MySQL they all help us to understand what MySQL does behind the scenes, but all provide the summary for the entire script overall. What would be the best way to identify these bottlenecks without profiling each each portion of the script separately? Are there best practices when faced with such problem?

Again, I apologize for asking a question that may be too broad. I can post and example code, but it may not be reproducible because there is no access to the actual database.

Comment: How many rows is it reading and returning in the result set? Hours is an extremely long time.

Comment: justiceorjustus, thank you for your comment. Lets suppose there are 2 tables that have 500k to 1mil rows each that are being appended together via `union` also each of these have 10-15 left joins with other tables that range from 10k to 500k rows. Number of columns is limited everywhere from only 2-3 columns to 15 columns

Comment: To be honest, that's not a lot of rows to be dealing with. I'm sorry I don't have much more substance to add, but it seems like a: your query is inefficient or b: your server doesn't perform well enough to handle it or c: you need to properly index your tables.  My best suggestion would be to look into best practices for querying and follow those rules.

Answer (score 2):

After using `EXPLAIN` and making sure I make use of proper indexing, I would run it on a subset of your data so I can get it in seconds (easier when tweaking the query).

I would run each subquery individually first and take a note how long they perform. Then run the query that calls that subquery/derived and see how long it performs. Comment out some subqueries and see how it performs. Soon you will get the picture which parts are your bottleneck.

Then I would start experimenting with different techniques. Perhaps using a temporary table first, or maybe I need to run daily cron jobs that summarizes the data for me.

> Therefore there are one or a few bottlenecks. Perhaps certain tables are not indexed properly.

This sounds like something you could solve using `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: Thank you Radius, for your reply. This is exactly what I have been doing. But since the query is huge (some of them are hundreds lines of code), and I am not aware which tables are used where without going through it manually. I was wondering may be there is a tool that makes this job easier.

Comment: Wow, that is huge. Current large query I'm working on is only 60 lines in comparison (with 3 derived tables).

I would try to definitely break them down when testing. But perhaps something that huge should be run on a slave/reporting DB on a scheduled task?

I'm also not aware of other tools other than MySQL bench.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use MySQL but this is sort of a software agnostic problem.  Assuming that you are already doing some of the "right" things such as filtering on indexed fields, etc, there are two steps that might help.

First - move the code to a Stored Procedure.  The benefit of this is that the code needs to be compile only once.  If your current query is not run frequently, it has to be compiled every time it runs, which takes time.

Second - use temporary tables.  While it's not intuitive, I have found that this often improves execution time dramatically.

Comment: Thank you Dan, I will look into those two things. I definitely don't have temp tables in my current setup